# List Index Out of Range- Python Pandas Topic Modeling (K-means Clustering)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set that has about 100,000 rows and I used a sample set of 1000. when i tried to do K-mean clustering, I am getting an error.

I grouped the data set into three different topics,and when I try to append them back to the original data frame, I am getting an error that is saying,

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I used the following to get the major topics and it works just  fine,

```
for topic in nmf.components_:
ID_index = np.argsort(topic)[::-1][:num_major_words ]
major_words.append([vocab [i] for i in Id_index ])
```

and then I had created a dictionary that has the unique ID's, next I have a for loop looks like this,(this works, but cuts off at 980 and gives that index error)

```
b = 0
for i in range(len(id_topic_grouped )):
    major_topic = np.argsort(id_major_grouped [i, :])[::-1][0:3]
    major_topic_str = " ".join(str(m) for m in major_topic)
    print ("{}:{}".format(IDs_sorted[i], major_topic_str))

    b += 1
```

As you can see, I counted the sorted topics that correlated with my major topics and I only got 980 of them and it said the `index out of range error!`

And then, here is how I merge them with the original ID's

```
dt_mc_clt = dt_mc_clt.append({"ID":IDs_sorted[i], "Topic One":int(major_topic[0]), "Topic Two":int(major_topic[1]), "Topic Three":int(major_topic[2])}, ignore_index= True)
```

Please ask me more question if this does not help or if its not clear, and any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please show your full traceback.

Comment: i have edited the original post, please look at that and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: What does `len(IDs_sorted)` say?